# Найти все организации внутри заданной области

Tags: yandex-maps-api, search

Как в API поиска по организациям от Яндекса найти все организации, находящиеся внутри определённой области (заданной параметрами ll+spn)? Обычно в запросе в параметре text мы указываем тип требуемой организации (например, аптеки), мне же нужны все организации (магазины, кафе, аптеки, банки и т.д.). Передавать координаты не вариант, так как тогда организация ищется только в заданной точке, а не области

Comment: Сервис не создан для выгрузки объектов в пользовательские базы. И подобные попытки с сохранением данных прямо нарушают условия использования сервиса, расширенной лицензии которого не существует. https://clck.ru/397847